# Log4j file location when running install4j created executable

Tags: log4j2, install4j

I have a GUI that I package into a Window exe using `install4j`.  In my GUI code, I used `log4j2`, specifying `SYSTEM_OUT` for `STDOUT`.  However, when I run the exe in Window, I do not see any logging.  I understand that the exe is not running in a console, but I don't understand how I can configure it to do what I want.

I tried to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file, but that file is not created.

I know my `log4j` configuration works, because my GUI can run under `JavaWebStart` with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection of stdout and stderr will not interfere with log4j or any other logging system unless you only log to the console.

In the log4j configuration, You have to configure an appender that logs to a writable file. If you install to the program files folder, the file cannot be in the installation directory because you will likely not have elevated privileges when running your application. Log to some folder in %APPDATA% instead.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the problem:  write privilege.  I gave the app full control for now, but will go back and change the installation directory to probably /Users/...